# Returning a string array as a single string from a method

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I have a string array variable.

```
private string[] _documents;
```

Values to it are assigned like this.

```
string[] _documents = { "doc1", "doc2", "doc3" };
```

And there's a method which adds a string to that array and returns it.

```
public string GetMail()
{
    return originalMessage + " " + _documents[0];
}
```

Defining `_documents[0]` returns only the first element of the array.

How can I return all the elements in the array? (*Kinda like what implode function does in PHP*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not familiar with PHP, but you can concatenate all elements of a string array with [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
return string.Join(" ", docs);
```

The first parameter is the separator; you can pass an empty string if you do not need separators.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GetMail()
{
    return originalMessage + string.Join(" ", _documents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over them and append each to the original string.

```
 public string GetMail(string[] docs, string originalMessage)
 {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.Length; i++)
              originalMessage = originalMessage + " " + docs[i];

         return originalMessage;
  }
```